# SQL: get attributes from nested query

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I return `d.title` or `u.name` in the outer `SELECT` clause?

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM components c 
INNER JOIN publications p 
ON c.id = p.component_id
AND p.document_id IN 
    (SELECT d.id FROM documents d WHERE user_id IN 
        (SELECT u.id FROM users u WHERE u.brand_id IN (39, 41)
    )
)
```

I get this error when I throw `d.title` in the top line:

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "d" LINE 1
```

The package I'm using needs these values returned on the top line to make any use out of them in the result.

**Structure**

A `User` has many `Documents`, and `Publications` is the join table between `Documents` and `Components`.

Comment: It would be easier to give a definitive answer if you showed the structure of the tables, but in general, using joins instead of IN clauses will let you refer to the tables to which you are applying criteria.

Comment: As @rd_nielsen said, you will need to join in these tables (p.document_id = documents.id and documents.user_id = users.id) if you want to reference them in the select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below query -

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, d.title, u.name
FROM components c 
INNER JOIN publications p ON c.id = p.component_id
INNER JOIN documents d ON d.id = p.document_id
INNER JOIN users u ON d.user_id = u.id
AND u.brand_id IN (39, 41)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That helps so much. Cheers!